# Partial subtraction of two multi-dimensional lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two multi-dimensional lists, for example:

```
ff = {{{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {8, 6}}}
ff2 = {{{3, 7}, {4, 1}, {8, 4}}}
```

I would like to subtract them but only in the second element, I want to obtain

```
ff2 - ff = {{{3, 5}, {4, -1}, {8, -2}}}
```

but I obtain

```
f2 - ff = {{{0, 5}, {0, -1}, {0, -2}}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If the first elements of each pair are not equal, what should happen? Or will that never happen?

Comment: It will never happen

Comment: `MapThread[#1 - #2*{0, 1} &, {ff, ff2}, 2]`?

Comment: @ydd thank you. It seems to work. What does the last 2 stand for?

Comment: It specifies the `Level` of `ff` and `ff2` to which `#1 - #2*{0, 1} &` is applied

Comment: This question can be interpreted and answered in different ways. **(1)** Subtraction in the second entry. **(2)** Subtraction in the second entry only if the first entries are similar for which `Merge` strategies are optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ff2 - Threaded[{0, 1}] ff
```

> ```
> {{{3, 5}, {4, -1}, {8, -2}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
ff = {{{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {8, 6}}};
ff2 = {{{3, 7}, {4, 1}, {8, 4}}};
```

**1.**

```
res = 
  Transpose[{ff2[[1]], ff[[1]]}] /. {{x_, a_}, {_, b_}} :> {x, a - b}
```

{{3, 5}, {4, -1}, {8, -2}}

**2.**

```
res =
 KeyValueMap[List] @
  GroupBy[Flatten[{ff, ff2}, 2], First -> Last, First @* Differences]
```

{{3, 5}, {4, -1}, {8, -2}}

**3.**

```
res =
 KeyValueMap[List] @
  Merge[First @* Differences] @ MapApply[Rule] @ Flatten[{ff, ff2}, 2]
```

{{3, 5}, {4, -1}, {8, -2}}

If you want the outermost brackets:

```
List @ res
```

{{{3, 5}, {4, -1}, {8, -2}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[subtract];
subtract[x_, y_] := If[x == y, x, x - y];
SetAttributes[subtract, Listable]
subtract[ff2, ff]
```

> `{{{3, 5}, {4, -1}, {8, -2}}}`

Comment: `Clear[subtract]; subtract = 
 Function[{x, y}, If[x == y, x, x - y], Listable]; subtract[ff2, ff]`

Answer (score 1):

```
ff3 = ff;
ff3[[All, All, 2]] //= ff2[[All, All, 2]] - # &;
ff3
```

> ```
> {{{3, 5}, {4, -1}, {8, -2}}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
ReplacePart[ff, p : {_, _, 2} :> ff2[[## & @@ p]] - ff[[## & @@ p]]]
```

> ```
> {{{3, 5}, {4, -1}, {8, -2}}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
ff2-ff.{{0,0},{0,1}}

(* {{{3,5},{4,-1},{8,-2}}} *)
```

Or

```
ff2 - Map[{0,Last@#}&, ff,{2}]

(* {{{3,5},{4,-1},{8,-2}}} *)
```